# Нормально ли если класс реализует два интерфейса

Tags: интерфейс

Нормально ли если класс реализует два интерфейса,каждый из которых
имеет такое же определение для константы PI?

Comment: Вынесите определение константы в отдельный интерфейс и пусть ваш класс реализует все три интерфейса.

Comment: Константа Пи через реализацию интерфейса? В военное время значение синуса может достигать четырех?

Comment: а язык какой? значение константы одинаковое?